# Reuse dictionary keys and values into reusable cells

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

Here is my dictionary:

```
Results = ["Orange Salad + Pasta with Salmon + Cheesecake": 464, 
"Orange Salad + Pesto Pasta + Crab Cake": 480, 
"Rice Salad + Pesto Pasta + Cheesecake white ": 538,
"Salad Endives + Salmon Pasta + Crab Cake ": 480,
"Salad Endives + Pesto Pasta + Crab Cake ": 450,
"Orange Salad + Salmon Pasta + Cake crab": 510]
```

How can update the dequeueReusableCell method to reuse keys and values and fill both labels for every cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CombinationCell", for: indexPath) as! CombinationTableViewCell

    cell.combinaisonLabel.text = ""
    cell.calories.text = ""

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a dictionary to hold your data, define a `struct` for each result then create an array of those structs.

```
struct NutritionInfo {
    let name: String
    let calories: Int
}
```

Then:

```
let results = [
    NutritionInfo(name: "Orange Salad + Pasta with Salmon + Cheesecake", calories: 464),
    NutritionInfo(name: "Orange Salad + Pesto Pasta + Crab Cake", calories: 480),
    // and the rest
]
```

Now that you have your data organized properly, your table view methods become:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CombinationCell", for: indexPath) as! CombinationTableViewCell

    let nutrition = results[indexPath.row]

    cell.combinaisonLabel.text = nutrition.name
    cell.calories.text = "\(nutrition.calories)"

    return cell
}
```

This approach has many advantages. You can easily and safely add additional details if needed. You can sort the table view as needed by sorting the array on whichever field you want.

Comment: results dictionary is a computed result from a closure, so I don't how to use it with struct.

Comment: `let array = results.map { NutritionInfo(name: $0, calories: $1) }`. That will convert your `results` dictionary into an array of `NutritionInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be:

1. create struct instead of dictionary

   ```
   struct dataModel {

     var foodName: String

     var calories: Int
   }
   ```
2. Keep struct object into array
3. Can access them using index of array and show the value in table cell.